# Why do I have to "composer install" whenever I switch to a branch? Does it kill my memory?

Tags: laravel, git, laravel-8

Context: I am roughly new to Laravel and Github. I am working on a project with 3 other people, and we have created all our individual branches. But every time, I switch to their branch (which I am to successfully) but whenever I am trying to run the server on port 8000 I get the following error:

> C:\Users\Einstein\Documents\Program\Project>php artisan serve
> PHP Warning:  require(C:\Users\Einstein\Documents\Program\laravel\Project/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Einstein\Documents\Program\laravel\Project\artisan on line 18

> Warning: require(C:\Users\Einstein\Documents\Program\laravel\Project/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Einstein\Documents\Program\laravel\Project\artisan on line 18
> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\Einstein\Documents\Program\laravel\Project/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\Einstein\Documents\Program\laravel\Project\artisan on line 18

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\Einstein\Documents\Program\laravel\Project/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users...8```

However, I am to run the project whenever I perform composer install. Why is that so? It seems like I have to rerun the packages whenever I am switches to branches, does it kill my computer memory? If I have to reinstall packages (this is my assumption whenever I perform composer install) will kill my computer memory.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your vendor folder inside the .gitignore?

Comment: @GertB. Yes Gert. Is that causing the issue?

Comment: No, if it was not in the .gitignore, that would cause the problem

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely because you are pulling in cached files calling the other peoples local paths and not yours. When you run `composer install` it pulls all the dependencies listed in the `composer.json` file to the `/vendor` folder, then rebuilds the config cache.

You can try and just rebuild the cache instead of re-installing all the dependencies with:

`composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan clear:cache`

Comment: Thanks for the swift response, I truly appreciate your help. I went to cmd (windows) and performed composer dump-autoload and I get this : No composer.json in current directory, do you want to use the one at C:\Users\Einstein\Documents\Program\laravel? [Y/n] I entered in "Y" and then  I get this: Class Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts is not autoloadable, can not call post-autoload-dump script

Comment: You have to run the commands from the root of your project.

Comment: It seems composer install only seems to solve the problem, the only issue that worried me is that am I killing memory on every instance I run composer install

Comment: I found something: https://mnapoli.fr/run-composer-install-when-you-switch-branch/